# Rails : Error while installing rubyracer (OS - Ventura) .`Could not get version string of compiler c++ (RuntimeError)`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, therubyracer

I would appreciate some help in getting `gem install therubyracer` to work. Here is the error:

```
Fetching therubyracer-0.12.0.gem
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing therubyracer:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.`

current directory: /Users/sidmallik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@emailmarketing/gems/libv8- 
3.16.14.19/ext/libv8
/Users/sidmallik/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/bin/ruby -I 
/Users/sidmallik/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0 -r 
./siteconf20230417-13868-1rqlxz3.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile
/Users/sidmallik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@emailmarketing/gems/libv8- 
3.16.14.19/ext/libv8/compiler.rb:44:in `version_string_of': Could not get version 
string of compiler c++ (RuntimeError)
from /Users/sidmallik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@emailmarketing/gems/libv8- 
3.16.14.19/ext/libv8/compiler.rb:32:in `type_of'
from /Users/sidmallik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@emailmarketing/gems/libv8- 
3.16.14.19/ext/libv8/compiler.rb:28:in `block in available_compilers'
from /Users/sidmallik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@emailmarketing/gems/libv8- 
3.16.14.19/ext/libv8/compiler.rb:28:in `map'
from /Users/sidmallik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@emailmarketing/gems/libv8- 
3.16.14.19/ext/libv8/compiler.rb:28:in `available_compilers'
from /Users/sidmallik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@emailmarketing/gems/libv8- 
3.16.14.19/ext/libv8/builder.rb:108:in `choose_compiler'
from /Users/sidmallik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@emailmarketing/gems/libv8- 
3.16.14.19/ext/libv8/builder.rb:16:in `initialize'
from /Users/sidmallik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@emailmarketing/gems/libv8- 
3.16.14.19/ext/libv8/location.rb:23:in `new'
from /Users/sidmallik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@emailmarketing/gems/libv8- 
3.16.14.19/ext/libv8/location.rb:23:in `install!'
from extconf.rb:7:in `<main>'

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/sidmallik/.rvm/gems/ruby- 
2.6.6@emailmarketing/gems/libv8-3.16.14.19 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/sidmallik/.rvm/gems/ruby- 
2.6.6@emailmarketing/extensions/x86_64-darwin-19/2.6.0/libv8-3.16.14.19/gem_make.out
```

Here are some notable steps that I ran before the error. They worked fine:

```
gem uninstall libv8
brew install v8
```

My environment is:

OS - Ventura
ruby 2.6.6 (via rvm)

Comment: That gem hasn't been updated since 2017 and is not in wide use. Are you sure you actually need that gem? If you do, are you sure you don't intend to use `mini_racer`? See https://github.com/rubyjs/therubyracer/issues/462 for more info.

Comment: I got it working .. Looks like command line tools were not installed . Running `xcode-select --install`  fixed it . Any thanks for the input

Comment: Without the compiler tools that are part of the "Xcode Command-Line Tools", compiled extensions can't be installed, so that should fix it.